# Apache Tomee & Hibernate ORM: Windows Server 2012 R2 or SuSE Linux Enterprise Server 11 SP4

Tags: hibernate, windows-server-2012, apache-tomee, suse

I am given the possibility to chose between **Windows Server 2012 R2** and **SuSE Linux Enterprise Server 11 SP4**, while renting a virtual server. For the needs of the server I want to create, I wish to install Apache TomEE as a web application server. I also intend to use the Hibernate ORM.

Is there any well known problems/bugs (still not fixed) regarding Apache TomEE or Hibernate, and one of the two OS I can choose between? Would anyone suggest one over the other, except the preference between Windows and Linux?

Answer (score 0):

## Windows vs Linux

What are you more comfortable administrating? If you have no Linux experience, definitely use Windows.

That being said, Linux offers thousands of advantages over Windows, from the ability to create LXC containers, to it's security record, it's lightweightness, it's remote administration capabilities. You also have the ability use thousands of portable UNIX command line tools, whereas with Windows, you're limited to non-portable powershell.

## Hibernate ORM

Generally I recommend people do not use Hibernate. Instead, stick to the official JPA annotations and APIs only, and let the application container choose your implementation.

If you require features from your ORM that are not provided by the vanilla JPA annotations, use them SPARINGLY, and infrequently. I cannot emphasize this enough.

If you must use non-standard ORM features, I would recommend EclipseLink. It's not only the fastest ORM, but it's very lightweight, and the error messages it produces when you make a mistake are *extremely* helpful.

Hibernate's codebase is unfortunately a mess because it carries so much legacy cruft. It was the game changing implementation, and JPA was born out of it, but there are much better options now.